# Ошбка list' object is not callable в Питоне

Tags: python

Помогите, пожалуйста, понять почему выходит ошибка

> TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

```
values = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42]
mean = 18
result = list(map(lambda x: x-18, values))
```

Answer (score 2):

приведённый код работает, вы случаем ранее не вводили переменные типа

```
list = []

values = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42]
mean = 18
result = list(map(lambda x: x-18, values))

print(result)
```

тогда такая ошибка возникнет

ибо не надо называть переменные ключевыми словами питона

Comment: спасибо! теперь получилось!